# Add static files to NextJS hot reloading

Tags: webpack, next.js

I use Next JS to create simple blog sites.

### Composition

```
- public
  - articles
     - [hoge]
        - index.md
- pages
  - article.tsx
```

Fetch and display `public/articles/[hoge]/index.md` in `article.tsx`

### Problem

Articles are edited as markdown files in an editor, and checked for display on a local development server.
When the markdown file is edited, hot reloading is not performed, so the browser must be manually updated.

Is there any way to add a static file (in the public folder) to monitor hot reloading?

### Tried

I added it to next.config.js, as described in [Watching Static Content](https://github.com/shellscape/webpack-plugin-serve/blob/master/recipes/watch-static-content.md).

```js
const sane = require('sane')
const { WebpackPluginServe: Serve } = require('webpack-plugin-serve')

const serve = new Serve({ static: ['./public/assets'] })
const watcher = sane('./public/assets', { glob: ['**/*.md'] })

serve.on('listening', () => {
  watcher.on('change', (filePath, root, stat) => {
    serve.emit('reload', { source: 'config' })
  })
})

serve.on('close', () => watcher.close())

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,

  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.plugins.push(serve)
    return config
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

#### ERROR

```
⬢ wps: webpack-plugin-serve adds HotModuleReplacementPlugin automatically. Please remove it from your config.
PluginExistsError: HotModuleReplacementPlugin exists in the specified configuration.
```

#### Additional Tried

```
delete config.plugins.HotModuleReplacementPlugin
```

```
config.plugins.HotModuleReplacementPlugin = serve
```

But nothing happend.

*I don't understand the basics of webpack, so I could be doing something incorrect.

Comment: did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @deadcoder0904 Nope. I had given up this.

Comment: well, i just found a solution to remove it using filter. it works :)

Answer (score 0):

to remove it, you can loop over the constructor name & filter it out by doing a string comparison.

```
const plugins = oldConfig.plugins.filter((plugin) => {
    if (
        plugin.constructor &&
        plugin.constructor.name === 'HotModuleReplacementPlugin'
    )
        return false
    return plugin
})

oldConfig.plugins = plugins
```

my full code:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const sane = require('sane')
const { WebpackPluginServe: Serve } = require('webpack-plugin-serve')

const serve = new Serve({ static: ['./styles'] })
const watcher = sane('./styles', { glob: ['**/*.css'] })

serve.on('listening', () => {
  watcher.on('change', (filePath, root, stat) => {
    console.log('file changed', filePath)
  })
})

serve.on('close', () => watcher.close())

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  rewrites: async () => {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        destination: '/index.html',
      },
    ]
  },
  webpack: (oldConfig, options) => {
    const plugins = oldConfig.plugins.filter((plugin) => {
      if (
        plugin.constructor &&
        plugin.constructor.name === 'HotModuleReplacementPlugin'
      )
        return false
      return plugin
    })

    oldConfig.plugins = plugins

    const config = {
      mode: 'development',
      watch: true,
      plugins: plugins.concat([serve]),
    }
    return merge(oldConfig, config)
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Comment: Thank you.
Surely the `console.log('file changed', filePath)` is executed when the stacic file is updated, but is it reloaded? Removing the `HotModuleReplacementPlugin`, even the HMR in the tsx file is gone.

But I was able to remove the existing config, so I'll give it some more thought when I have more time.

Comment: @KK watch `ts` files as well using `sane`... idk a good solution to your problem but just found out a quick solution to remove `HotModuleReplacementPlugin` so posted that :)